# unable to make a scroll progress effect with framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

i am trying to make a scroll effect where when you scroll then the progress bar will increase in width, but i have tried to do it and its not working with framer motion's useScroll and useSpring hook.Here is my code

```
    import { Grid, Stack, Typography, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { motion, useScroll, useSpring, useTransform } from "framer-motion";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
const ProgressLineStyled = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  height: "10px",
  borderRadius: "10px",
  backgroundColor: "white",
}));
function Projects() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    container: ref,
    offset: ["end end", "start start"],
  });
  const scalesX = useSpring(scrollYProgress, { damping: 30, stiffness: 100 });
  return (
    <Grid
      sx={{ pt: 12 }}
      height="100%"
      position="relative"
      component={motion.div}
      border="12px solid"
      container
    >
      <Grid
        component={motion.div}
        display={"flex"}
        flexDirection={"column"}
        item
        xs={11}
        ref={ref}
      >
        <Stack
          component={motion.div}
          direction={"column"}
          justifyContent={"center"}
          alignItems={"center"}
          position={"sticky"}
          top="50px"
          left="0%"
          gap={2}
        >
          <Typography component={motion.div} color="orange" variant={"h4"}>
            Projects
          </Typography>
          <ProgressLineStyled
            component={motion.div}
            style={{ scaleX: scalesX }}
          ></ProgressLineStyled>
        </Stack>
        {Array(5)
          .fill(null)
          .map((e, i) => {
            return (
              <section className="section">
                <span>work {i}</span>
              </section>
            );
          })}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

also here is the css of section tag :

```
.section{
        height:100vh;
        scroll-snap-align: center;
    }
```

can anyone tell me what mistake i am making?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `style={{ scaleX: scalesX }}` on `ProgressLineStyled` component. Wouldn't it be `style={{ transform: 'scaleX(' + scalesX + ')' }}` ?
Also ScaleX will not work for an element with `0` width. You can try use `'width: ' + scalesX + '%'` or set the width as `1%` additionally with scale

Comment: i think the problem is with useScroll bc when i did console.log(scalesX.get(), scrollYProgress.get(), "get") in useEffect then i got 0,0 everytime